# How to recover the - Accidently selected "No" option for "open recent files" in Mousepad text editor

Tags: xubuntu

I've been using mousepad text editor for simple tasks in my Xubuntu 22.10. And I've 2 important tabs

1. notes.txt (has some unsaved data)
2. A file (not created in disk)

I often save my data before shutdown the pc but even if I didn't during the next power on when I open the mousepad will prompt the option to open the recent files and my unsaved data is gotten back, unfortunately this time I accidentally selected "No" to the option and
now the file which has unsaved data is also gone and the data the file is not created is also gone.(I agree this is how it suppose to work)

But I need to recover this data back. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Yes looked in to `~/.cache` there's no `mousepad` dir. This is not about deleting the file, this is about an unsaved file which contained data accidentally closed before saving. I guess there should be a way this data is stored temporarily some other location or a way to extract from any

Comment: i've updated. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `~/.local/share/Mousepad/autosave-0`

I booted a Xubuntu 22.10 ISO, opened `mousepad` and typed a few lines containing only "blah"... I then killed the editor (`killall mousepad`) and my few lines of 'blah' were located in

`~/.local/share/Mousepad/autosave-0`

On restarting `mousepad`, I was asked the question you say you received.

- If I answered "Yes" or just hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> the few lines of 'blah' appeared in the editor window,however
- on answering "No", the aforementioned file was erased.

As you answered "No", and the file was erased; you'll need to recover deleted file(s).  See this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) on file recovery.

This was all done with Xubuntu 22.10.